# JPQL Query giving no results when adding additional OR condition

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to construct a where clause where a value exists either in a list or in a list of lists. The query itself is quite long, so I'll just post the WHERE-clause

```
WHERE site.siteID = ?3 AND items.itemID = ?4  AND  ( ?5 MEMBER OF itemData.listValue )
```

I've tried it for a specific site and itemID and I get 3 results back which is correct. Now I've tried to also include the list of lists, but that doesn't work:

```
WHERE site.siteID = ?3 AND items.itemID = ?4  AND  ( ?5 MEMBER OF itemData.listValue OR ?6 MEMBER OF itemListData.listValue)
```

This does not throw an exception, it just returns 0 results (parameters 5 and 6 are of the same value).

Here are the (shortened) corresponding entities:

```
public Site{
    private Item item;
    private List<Item> items;
}

public Item{
    private List<String> listValue;
}
```

So really what I'm trying to do is select all entities where the passed value is either in item.listValue OR in any of the items.listValue. What baffles me is that the addition of an OR condition reduces the result set. I would much prefer a data model where Site.item is moved to the list of items, but I sadly cannot change the entities. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wonder what the SQL invoked by your JPA provider is? That is where you find info on what is "wrong"

Comment: Could it be that this part `itemListData.listValue` added `inner join` to your SQL query and you have no values for `listValue`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll check the generated SQL and report back!

Comment: There is definitely no new (inner) join in the output SQL. Any ideas on how to write the "?6 MEMBER OF itemListData.listValue)" part?

Comment: I still don't understand the behavior but I was able to solve the problem by inserting a subquery where I select all items based with "? MEMBER OF item.listValue" and checking the whether the items of the site occur in the subquery.